# StackExchange Number Format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I've grown to love the StackExchange number format for question views: after a particular question passes `1000` views, the view count is displayed as `1k`.  This format has become second-nature to me, and is very easy to understand.

**How can I implement this number format in Excel?**

As an example, see below:

[image: Data with general number format]

I want to make the bar chart labels to display `10.2k`, `1k`, and `626`, respectively.  (I want to use the format in a budget display, but I'm using SE reputation because it's safe to share.)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a method that seems to work, but it has some room for improvement.  (I'm still looking for other options, even though I'm posting this.)

**Use the number format code:** `[<1000]0;[>=1000]#.0,k`

This displays the just the number (no decimals) if it's less than `1000`.  If the number is greater than `1000`, then it displays the number divided by `1000` and rounded to one decimal with a following `k`.

Applied to the prior example:

[image: Data with SE number format]

Notice that, since this is a number format and not a formula, it can be applied to any number (even the axis labels).

**Problem:** This doesn't quite fit the question's requirements, because it would be best to output `1k` instead of `1.0k`.  I can get rid of the unnecessary zero with a `#` instead of a `0` in the format string, but it leaves the `.`.

Comment: I've not played with custom number formats much, but can you specify a 3rd range? if so make when to display 1k a 3rd condition.

Comment: You don't need two conditions, just one, then the next part of the format is used for everything else. So [>=1000]#.0,k;0 would work. You can get rid of the trailing zero by using #.#,k instead, but that still leaves the trailing decimal point.

Comment: @Tyson you can have multiple conditions, but that would only deal with 1K, not 2K, which would then look even more consistent